# Table Not Rendering Properly with Async | PHP | API | LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, laravel, asynchronous, html-table

I have this async code , but when i try to render inside a table  , the table become a mess (image) but after a page refresh the table is perfctly fine and i dont know why ,  how can i fix this problem ?

and if is possible to have a better async code , i know i need to async the
`$api->getMatchTimeline($match->gameId);` but i don't know how can i do it.

```
   

   <table class="table table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
     <thead>
       <th>Items</th>
      </thead>
    </tr>
  
<tbody>

  <?php
$onSuccess = function (Objects\MatchDto $match) use (&$api, $champ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    foreach ($match->participants as $partId) {
        if ($partId->championId == $champ) {
            $participant_id = $partId->stats->participantId;
            $pp = $api->getMatchTimeline($match->gameId);
            foreach ($pp->frames as $p) {
                foreach ($p->events as $t) {
                    if ($t->type == "ITEM_PURCHASED" and $t->participantId == $participant_id) {
                        $item_id = $t->itemId;
                        $d = $api->getStaticItem($item_id);
                        $depth = $d->depth;
                        if (($depth == 3 or $depth == 2)) {
                            echo "<a href = https://lolprofile.net/match/kr/$match->gameId#Match%20History >";
                            echo "<img src =" . DataDragonAPI::getItemIconUrl($item_id) . " />" . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
};
$onFailure = function ($ex) {
    echo $ex;
};
foreach ($database as $game) {
    $api->nextAsync($onSuccess);
    $match = $api->getMatch($game->match_ids);
}
$api->commitAsync();
?>

     </tbody>
     </table>
```

[image]

render outside the table

[image]

Comment: PHP doesn't support `async` programming (without hacking around with a fake event-loop or `pthreads`). What database library are you using? I don't see `commitAsync` in Laravel's documentation.

Comment: Also, you should really not be doing _business logic_ (like saving to a database) inside your render function.

Comment: Please post the **rendered HTML**, not just a screenshot.

Comment: im not saving anything on the database  with this code , the game IDs are coming from my db and this is the api  i'm using https://github.com/dolejska-daniel/riot-api it comes with guzzle http

Comment: Indent your code better please

Comment: @Dai i've updated with a better image ,  the code is rendering outside the <table> ,and i dont know why ,  all the code is inside the <table>

Comment: @LucasLn Your table HTML is incorrect: `<tr>` is a child of `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, not a parent.

Comment: Why are you using a `<table>` when you only have 1 column?

Comment: @dai even with <li> the code gets messed up when i enter the page for the first time ,  i guess the async is messing up the <tr> <thead> , because when i refresh the page everything works as suposed to

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: 8 from xampp @Dai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't to do with your "async" PHP code, but because your `<table>` markup is incorrect.

HTML's `<table>` element has two different forms. The first is the "implicit `<tbody>` form, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The other has an explicit `<tbody>` element, which can also optionally have a `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` (you can also have multiple `<tbody>` but only a single `<thead>`. You *can* use a `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` with an implicit `<tbody>` but this is not recommended - I recommend everyone use the explicit syntax, like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the actual DOM representation of both tables is the same: in the DOM a `<table>` never has `<tr>` as immediate children.

---

Secondarily, you can also make your code a LOT easier to read and follow if you separate your application logic from your rendering logic by doing all of your API calls and whatnot at the start of your PHP script and populate a "view model" object and then the rendering logic is greatly simplfied, like so:

```
<?php
// This PHP block should be before *any* HTML is written:

class MatchAndItems {
    public Objects\MatchDto $match;
    public Array $items;
}

$allMatches = Array(); # Array of `MatchAndItems`.

$onFailure = function ($ex) {
    echo $ex;
};

$gotMatch = function (Objects\MatchDto $match) use (&$api, $champ, $allMatches) {
    
    $e = new MatchAndItems();
    $e->match = $match;
    $e->items = array();

    foreach ($match->participants as $partId) {
        if ($partId->championId == $champ) {
            $participant_id = $partId->stats->participantId;
            $pp = $api->getMatchTimeline($match->gameId);
            foreach ($pp->frames as $p) {
                foreach ($p->events as $t) {
                    if ($t->type == "ITEM_PURCHASED" and $t->participantId == $participant_id) {
                        $item_id = $t->itemId;
                        $d       = $api->getStaticItem($item_id);

                        array_push( $e->items, $d );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    array_push( $allMatches, $e );
};

# Set-up web-service HTTP request batches:
foreach( $database as $game ) {
    $api->nextAsync( $gotMatch )->getMatch( $game->match_ids );
}

# Invoke the batch:
$api->commitAsync();

# The below code uses https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

?>

<!-- etc -->


<table class="table table table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php    foreach( $allMatches as $match ): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
<?php
            foreach( $match->items as $item ):

                if( $item->depth == 2 or $item->depth == 3 ):
                     echo "<a href = https://lolprofile.net/match/kr/$match->gameId#Match%20History >";
                     echo "<img src =" . DataDragonAPI::getItemIconUrl($item_id) . " />" . '</a>';
                endif;

            endforeach;
?>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's one problem ,  outside the $gotMatch function the $allMatches is empty  @Dai

Comment: @LucasLn Yes, that's because `$gotMatch` is used to populate `$allMatches`. Do you have PHP debugger or IDE you can use? When is the `nextAsync` callback invoked, exactly?

Comment: I got it ,  adding (&$api, $champ , &allmatches) and now i can access outside the function , but now  it says $item is undefined @Dai

Comment: The documentation at https://github.com/dolejska-daniel/riot-api says that the "async" API is really just a batching system - which are all invoked when `commitAsync` is called ( https://github.com/dolejska-daniel/riot-api/wiki/LeagueAPI:-Asynchronous-requests ) - but they have a weird callback convention - but updating my code to use it correctly should be straightforward.

Comment: @LucasLn I've updated my code after I saw some other errors - I think it should work now.

Comment: we are close ,  it says Undefined property: MatchAndItems::$gameId
EDITED : i got it , correct is  $match->match->gameId

Comment: tks for the help , after a few modifications , is working like a charm